# Why does \renewcommand{\A}{\B} change the value of \C? when \A, \B, and \C are arguments?

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm very puzzled by the effect of a `\renewcommand` with two macros as arguments that appears to affect the value of a third macro. This all occurs within a command to which all three macros are passed as arguments. Here's an MWE; I've printed intermediate values of relevant variables to isolate where the "problem" is occurring:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mA}{3.1}
\newcommand{\mB}{0}
\newcommand{\mC}{8.2}
\newcommand{\saveSwapValue}[3]{%
\noindent
Before executing either \texttt{\textbackslash{}renewcommand}:\\
\#1: #1\\
\#2: #2\\
\#3: #3\\
    \renewcommand{#2}{#1}
After \texttt{\textbackslash{}renewcommand\{\#2\}\{\#1\}}  \\
\#1: #1\\
\#2: #2\\
\#3: #3\\
    \renewcommand{#1}{#3}
After \texttt{\textbackslash{}renewcommand\{\#1\}\{\#3\}}  \\
\#1: #1\\
\textcolor{red}{\#2: #2}\\
\#3: #3\\
}
\begin{document}
\saveSwapValue{\mA}{\mB}{\mC}
\texttt{\textbackslash{}mB}: \mB.\\
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

The unexpected result is highlighted in red: The value of the second argument, `\mB`, was changed by `\renewcommand{\mA}{\mC}`. I would have expected instead that `\mB` would have been unaffected by this second `\renewcommand`.

I'd sure appreciate being enlightened about what I'm not understanding!

Comment: Most likely: use `\let #2 = #1` instead of `\renewcommand{#2}{#1}`, and so on for the others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that with `\renewcommand{<cmd>}{<stuff>}`, any subsequent use of `<cmd>` is *replaced* with `<stuff>`. Viewed differently, using a more practical example,

```
\renewcommand{\mB}{\mA}
```

just replaces `\mB` with `\mA` - not whatever is stored in `\mA` - with every call to `\mB`. That's because (La)TeX doesn't *expand* the value of `\mA` at the time of (re)definition of `\mB` when using `\renewcommand`.

So, after `\renewcommand{\mB}{\mA}` (`->` below should be interpreted as *expansion*),

```
\mA -> 3.1
\mB -> \mA -> 3.1
```

Then, after `\renewcommand{\mA}{\mC}`,

```
\mA -> \mC -> 8.2
\mB -> \mA -> \mC -> 8.2
\mC -> 8.2
```

If you wanted to *copy* the value of `\mA` into `\mB` (in an *expanded* fashion), then you can try `\edef` or `\let` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\saveSwapValueA}[3]{%
  \noindent
  Before executing either \texttt{\string\renewcommand}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2 \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
      \renewcommand{#2}{#1}
  After \texttt{\string\renewcommand\string{\string#2\string}\string{\string#1\string}}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2 \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
      \renewcommand{#1}{#3}
  After \texttt{\string\renewcommand\string{\string#1\string}\string{\string#3\string}}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \textcolor{red}{\#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2} \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
}

\newcommand{\saveSwapValueB}[3]{%
  \noindent
  Before executing either \texttt{\string\let}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2 \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
      \let#2=#1
  After \texttt{\string\let\string#2=\string#1}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2 \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
      \let#1=#3
  After \texttt{\string\let\string#1=\string#3}: \\
  \#1: \texttt{\string#1}: #1 \\
  \textcolor{red}{\#2: \texttt{\string#2}: #2} \\
  \#3: \texttt{\string#3}: #3 \\
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mA}{3.1}
\newcommand{\mB}{0}
\newcommand{\mC}{8.2}

\saveSwapValueA{\mA}{\mB}{\mC}

\renewcommand{\mA}{3.1}
\renewcommand{\mB}{0}
\renewcommand{\mC}{8.2}

\saveSwapValueB{\mA}{\mB}{\mC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was exactly the explanation, in terms of the degree of expansion a command does, that I needed to understand.